# Exception handling in Micronaut

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, micronaut

Is there a way in micronaut to throw an exception that will specify the error code for the response, in the same way we can do in springboot:

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
```

or do we always have to implement our own exception handler?

I would rather not have to implement exception handers just to be able to return a 400 or 403 response.

Comment: Are you using the Micronaut Security library?

Comment: If your controller return HttpResponse, you can just return an HttpResponse 403. But it's a good practice to have handler for specific exception handling.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no, not yet using the security library. only taking my first steps to understand how it works.

Comment: @Anorgar I will experiment with that, thank you.

Comment: It isn't really clear in what context you want to do this.  https://docs.micronaut.io/2.4.0/api/io/micronaut/http/exceptions/HttpStatusException.html may be relevant.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes, that's exactly it, thank you

Comment: Answer your questions in the answer section next time.  I've moved your answer to a Community Wiki so that it's easier for others to find it.

Comment: "Answer your questions in the answer section next time." - I don't think that is the right thing to have done.  I didn't have an answer.  I had a question and a comment that might be relevant, depending on the answer to the question I asked.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown:  The remark wasn't aimed at you.

Comment: @Makoto right, thank you! I'll make sure to do that next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class I wanted is:

```
io.micronaut.http.exceptions.HttpStatusException
```

I did not find it at first because I was missing the dependency:

```
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http")
```

I am using it to successfully return a 404 error with a message in this example:

```
fun findById(id: Long): User {
    val user = userRepository.findById(id)
    return if (user.isPresent()) user.get() else throw HttpStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User not found")
}
```

Feel free to comment if this is decent kotlin code. I am quite new to kotlin, from a java and scala background. Looks decent to me xD

Comment: your DAO/repository probably shouldn't be returning HTTP exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Just one trick, if you want to avoid the return statement you can update your method to use "the kotlin full powers"

Something like this:

```
fun findById(id: Long): User = 
    userRepository.findById(id)
        ?.let { it.orElseThrow(HttpStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User not found"))}
```

This is a use for **safe-call operator** and the transformation method `let` that get your entity or throw an Exception if not found it.

Comment: fun findById(id: Long): User = 
    userRepository.findById(id) ?: 
    throw HttpStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User not found")